# Is it possible to calculate liquibase:diff with liquibase-hibernate plugin and hibernate orm xml?

Tags: hibernate, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

I am aware of `liquibase:diff` which could give me the difference scripts between my databases.

I am trying to generate the difference scripts between my database and my `jpa entity`.

I have my hibernate `orm.xml` of my `jpa entity` and I want to find out the difference scripts using liquibase-hibernate plugin.

Is this possible, if so how can it be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Documentation here indicates it is possible to compare a hibernate entity model: https://www.liquibase.org/blog/liquibase-diffs.

Although I have not tried this, I think you would use org.hibernate.dialect.<[specificdb](https://vladmihalcea.com/jdbc-driver-connection-url-strings/)>
for the driver.